# Adjusting the edge on this figure to fit into the margins?

Tags: tikz-pgf, typography

Consider:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{rsfso}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel, arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,maxbibnames=99,sortcites=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}
\begin{figure} \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 11mm and 33mm,
     N/.style = {draw, minimum size=12mm, inner sep=0pt},
            > = {Stealth[scale=0.6]},
 every edge/.append style = {draw, ->},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\small\linespread{0.75}\selectfont,
                                   inner sep=5pt, sloped}
                        ]
\node [N] (A) {$S$};
\node [N,above right=of A] (B) {$I_1$};
\node [N,below right=of A] (C) {$I_2$};
\node [N,above right=of C] (D) {$J$};
\node [N,right=of D] (E)  {$A$};
%
\draw [<-] (A) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$\mu$};
\draw [->] (A) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu S$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=3.75mm] B.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\nu I_1$};
\draw [->] (C) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu I_2$};
\draw [->] (D) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu J$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=-3.5mm] E.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\alpha A$};
\draw [->] ([xshift=+3.5mm] E.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\nu A$};
%
\draw   ([yshift=+1mm] A.east)
            edge [ultra thick, draw=gray,"\slash\slash\slash" anchor=center,
                  "$\begin{gathered}
                        p\beta_1 S I_2\\
                        q\beta_2 S J\\
                        r\beta_3 S A
                    \end{gathered}$" ] (B.west)
        ([yshift=-1mm] A.east)
            edge [ultra thick, draw=gray,"\slash\slash\slash" anchor=center,
                  "$\begin{gathered}
                        (1-p)\beta_2 S I_2\\
                        (1-q)\beta_2 S J\\
                        (1-r)\beta_3 S A
                    \end{gathered}$" '] (C.west)
       (B) edge [rotate=90,"$\epsilon I_1$"] (C)
        (D.west) edge ["$\xi_1 J$"  ] ( B.east)
        ( C.east) edge ["$p_1 I_2$"  ] (D.west)
        ([yshift=-2mm] D.west) edge ["$\xi_2 J$" '] ([yshift=-2mm] C.east)
    (D) edge ["$p_2 J$"] (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}
\caption{Flow diagram for the HIV/AIDS model.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How can I make this figure fit within the margins? We can either scale it or reduce the line edge from "J" to "A". I think the latter is better but I await your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is general (I use it in cases that "I have" to use a unit):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,showframe]{book}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{rsfso}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel, arrows.meta, positioning, quotes, calc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,maxbibnames=99,sortcites=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} \centering
\def\mscale{0.93}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=0.9,
node distance = {11*\mscale mm} and {33*\mscale mm},
     N/.style = {draw, minimum size={12*\mscale mm}, inner sep=0pt},
            > = {Stealth[scale={0.6*\mscale}]},
 every edge/.append style = {draw, ->},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\small\linespread{0.75}\selectfont,
                                   inner sep={5*\mscale pt}, sloped}
                        ]
\node [N] (A) {$S$};
\node [N,above right=of A] (B) {$I_1$};
\node [N,below right=of A] (C) {$I_2$};
\node [N,above right=of C] (D) {$J$};
\node [N,right=of D] (E)  {$A$};
%
\draw [<-] (A) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$\mu$};
\draw [->] (A) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu S$};
\draw [->] ([xshift={3.75*\mscale mm}] B.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\nu I_1$};
\draw [->] (C) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu I_2$};
\draw [->] (D) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu J$};
\draw [->] ([xshift={-3.5*\mscale mm}] E.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\alpha A$};
\draw [->] ([xshift={3.5*\mscale mm}] E.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {$\nu A$};
%
\draw   ([yshift={1*\mscale mm}] A.east)
            edge [ultra thick, draw=gray,"\slash\slash\slash" anchor=center,
                  "$\begin{gathered}
                        p\beta_1 S I_2\\
                        q\beta_2 S J\\
                        r\beta_3 S A
                    \end{gathered}$" ] (B.west)
        ([yshift={-1*\mscale mm}] A.east)
            edge [ultra thick, draw=gray,"\slash\slash\slash" anchor=center,
                  "$\begin{gathered}
                        (1-p)\beta_2 S I_2\\
                        (1-q)\beta_2 S J\\
                        (1-r)\beta_3 S A
                    \end{gathered}$" '] (C.west)
       (B) edge [rotate=90,"$\epsilon I_1$"] (C)
        (D.west) edge ["$\xi_1 J$"  ] ( B.east)
        ( C.east) edge ["$p_1 I_2$"  ] (D.west)
        ([yshift={-2*\mscale mm}] D.west) edge ["$\xi_2 J$" '] ([yshift={-2*\mscale mm}] C.east)
    (D) edge ["$p_2 J$"] (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}
\caption{Flow diagram for the HIV/AIDS model.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As an addition (I used the `tikzlibrary` `calc`)

My way ... multiply every dimension with a defined `\mscale` (my scale) and add the option `scale=\mscale` to the `tikzpicture`'s optional argument.

In other cases that you don't have to use units... Don't use them... The scale will work in such cases

Extra (add `font=\mfont` as an extra command for each node to be able to lower or increase font size too if needed)

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome @Math ... Happy TeXing ...